# Azure Cloud Shell Failed to request a terminal

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

Through the web portal I can request a Cloud Shell, but it fails to request a terminal. Does anyone know how to trouble shoot this?

I've deleted my Storage Account. This prompts me to create a new Storage Account when I reopen Cloud Shell from the web portal. After creating the new Storage Account, I still have a Failed to request a terminal message.

Requesting a Cloud Shell.Succeeded.
Connecting terminal...

Failed to request a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and I found following:

1. Press F12 - go to developer mode (console)
2. You can see there ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
3. visit that link and click in your browser: "Proceed to *.westeurope.console.azure.com (unsafe)"
4. you get error (it's OK)
5. Return back to Azure and close and open terminal

I hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that you need to configure your network settings to enable sending https requests and WebSocket requests to domains at *.console.azure.com. Take a look at the error [Failed to connect terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/troubleshooting#terminal-output---error-failed-to-connect-terminal-websocket-cannot-be-established-press-enter-to-reconnect).